# Logging via decorators in python - function called twice?

Tags: python, exception, decorator

I am trying to log expectations via decorators and came across a code snippet (see below)

```
from functools import wraps

def logged(log='trace'):
    def wrap(function):
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            logger = logging.getLogger(log)
            logger.debug("Calling function '{}' with args={} kwargs={}"
                             .format(function.__name__, args, kwargs))
            try:
                response = function(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as error:
                logger.debug("Function '{}' raised {} with error '{}'"
                                 .format(function.__name__,
                                         error.__class__.__name__,
                                         str(error)))
                raise error
            logger.debug("Function '{}' returned {}"
                             .format(function.__name__,
                                     response))
            return response
        return wrapper
    return wrap 


@logged()
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

The code works fine but say if I call add(2,3) it appears the add function is called twice, once inside the decorator (added value stored in response variable) and then when I actually call add(2,3) somewhere in my code.

Is my understanding correct ? If so I would ideally want the decorator to only do the following:

- print "Calling function" with args
- If exception occurs when I call add(2,3) log the error. This should happen without doing `response = function(*args, **kwargs)` in the decorator

Is that possible ?

Comment: Add a print statement to the `add` function, then check how often the function is actually called. It is called just once

Comment: The *name* `add` isn't bound to your original function, only the wrapper defined in your decorator. Your *original* function is only referenced by the name `function` inside the wrapper.

Comment: Without decorator syntax, you would write `add = logged()(add)`, which makes it a little easier to see how the value of the name `add` changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it appears the add function is called twice [...] Is my understanding correct?

No. You need to understand that a decorator is nothing but syntactic sugar for a function that (typically) takes a callable object (i.e. function) as an argument and returns a callable/function.

In this case there are a few layers of nesting, but ultimately, what you have after the interpreter gets to the end of the definition of the decorated function, is the inner function `wrapper` that masquerades as the `add` function.

That wrapper is what is called, when you later on call `add(2, 3)`. And by its definition it will in turn call the "actual" `add`, passed to the definition of `wrapper` as the argument `function` of `wrap`.

Before that, the "actual" add is not called because the wrapper is not called. `add` is merely passed as a callable to the inner decorator and used to construct the `wrapper` function. The `wrapper` function is then returned to you after decoration.

> This should happen without doing `response = function(*args, **kwargs)` in the decorator

If you don't call `function` somewhere in there, the actual function (in this case `add`) will never be called.